# How do I change this function from mysql to pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

I have the following code to display userdata from the database easily.

If the user is logged in i can echo something like `$user_data['username']`.

```
if (logged_in() === true) {
    $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password_recover', 'type', 'allow_email', 'profile');
```

Using this function:

```
function user_data($user_id) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);

        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"));

        return $data;
    }
}
```

But this function is mysql obviously, and I have no idea how to change it to PDO, so I hoped someone else did.

This is the only code in my **connect.php** to connect with the database (PDO), which I include in every page.

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=###", '###', '###');
```

Comment: Read up on [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) and searching for related tutorials. We don't convert code, but work with existing issues. You just need to work with this line `$data = mysql_fetch_assoc...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

function user_data($user_id){

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname=db;", "user", "password");
$data = array();
$user_id = (int)$user_id;

$func_num_args = func_num_args();
$func_get_args = func_get_args();

if ($func_num_args > 1) {
    unset($func_get_args[0]);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
    $query = "SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $data;
}
}
```

That is not the best solution, but should do for now. Consider using prepared statements with bound parameters.

fyi: This isnt tested, but should work. If your implosion code is correct, then there should be no problem. Actually only added PDO connection creation and executed prepared query without parameters and after that fetched result as associative array.